# Trying to Plot with Seaborn: Error: InvalidURL: URL can't contain control characters. '/mwaskom/seaborn-data/master/

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I'm receiving the error: InvalidURL: URL can't contain control characters. '/mwaskom/seaborn-data/master/" when I try to plot a scatter plot with Seaborn

Seaborn imported fine, without any errors. As did my dataset. While I feel the error doesn't have to do with my code, here's my code for the scatterplot, just in case.

```
cfcudebt= sns.load_dataset(df)
scat = sns.scatterplot(x="Estimated_Income_CodeHHImp7", y="TotalLoansIND", data=cfcudebt)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm glad you included your code!
The function `sns.load_dataset()` gets data from the web.
You don't need that here.
So simply do this:

```
scat = sns.scatterplot(x="Estimated_Income_CodeHHImp7",y="TotalLoansIND",data=df)
```

What is happening is that `sns.load_dataset()` expects a string so it's doing something like `str(df)`, and then there are control characters -- namely `\n` -- in that result which cause the error you're seeing.

Comment: It's always something obvious when I have an error. Lol. Thanks for your input!

Comment: No problem. As you get more experienced your errors will get far less obvious. Something to look forward to!